# How to link 2 wordpress websites

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way or pluggin to link 2 wordpress websites together which means when i publish a post in the first site, the second one publish the same post automatically.
notice that 2 sites on the same host.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into this few months ago for a project which one of the requirements was to automatically duplicate posts between Wordpress sites, short answer is yes, but out of the box you can't.

Long answer:

Yes, you can have three different scenarios:

1. You can clone posts manually through different blogs sitting in a multi-site installation using the [Multisite Post Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-post-duplicator/) plugin, this however requires you to move both websites within a single installation of wordpress and make them run into multi-site mode. Also, you will need to manually duplicate them.
2. You can install on the second website a WPAuto plugin (there are few options out there, so I am not going to link every single one) which allows you to import automatically some RSS feeds into your second website. However RSS feeds must be enabled on the first website to make these plugin fetch correctly the content, on top of that the content won't be created instantly but it will be fetched after a certain amount of time, (5/10 mins interval, maybe more, according to the plugin and host settings)
3. You can develop something custom, you can open up a REST endpoint on the second website and through the Wordpress APIs create programmatically a new post for each request received. On the First website you need to hook your Publish post function to send the data across to the second website to process it. As far as I am aware there are no plugins which does that so you'll have to do something on your own, requires a bit of time and you need to keep in considerations all the security implications in doing that.

Needless to say that I strongly hope you have access to both websites and the content you are trying to clone is yours or you have been authorized to republish it from the original author.

Comment: When i tried to install the plugin it gives me this error
Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_sites() in /hermes/bosnaweb04a/b764/ipg.qwe/test/wp-content/plugins/multisite-post-duplicator/mpd.php on line 25

Comment: That's because you are trying to install a multi-site wordpress plugin into a single-site wordpress, you must convert both your websites into a unique multi-site installation for that. You can find all the infos you need here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network